# Can COM server can call method inside MFC Client ?

Tags: com

Apart from Connection points ,,Is there any way a Method inside my COM server can call method inside MFC Client ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Connection points are exactly that - a mechanism to execute a callback on client. You can implement another COM interface on client to call from server, but I don't see the benefits.  Or you can implement some other type of remote interface via TCP sockets, pipes... everything more complicated than connection points.

Comment: Thanks  Zdeslav for your reply...Can we make a call from Server to Client...Here my Server is COM Server and Cient is MFC app ? if yes can you please help...

Comment: I have alerady answered that and listed a few ways to do it.